# Mouse Coordinates keep getting on top of one another -Java

Tags: java, jpanel

I am trying to get the mouse coordinates display in the panel but each time I move the cursor the message and new coordinates are being displayed on the previous one.I am using MouseMotionListener with JPanel. I can't figure out the problem.

[image]

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;
public class Main extends JPanel implements MouseMotionListener {
public JLabel label;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
      new Main();
      JFrame frame = new JFrame();
      frame.setTitle("MouseCoordinates");
      frame.setSize(400, 400);
      frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent we) {
        System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        Container contentPane = frame.getContentPane();
        contentPane.add(new Main());
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
      public Main() {
      setSize(400, 400);
      label = new JLabel("No Mouse Event Captured", JLabel.CENTER);
      add(label);
      addMouseMotionListener(this);
    }
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
    label.setText("Mouse Cursor Coordinates => X:" + e.getX() + " |Y:" + e.getY());
    }
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {}
    }
```

Comment: did you understand my answer?

Comment: Not completely.

Comment: you're creating your jpanel twice, and the the writing appears twice. test my answer and see if it works

Comment: It Works..
Thank You.

Comment: no problem, happy to help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating `Main` twice.

```
public class Main extends JPanel implements MouseMotionListener {
public JLabel label;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Main m = new Main();// create an object and reference it
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setTitle("MouseCoordinates");
    frame.setSize(400, 400);
    frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent we) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });
    Container contentPane = frame.getContentPane();
    contentPane.add(m);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
//...
```

your problem was creating the `Main` object twice (which is a jpanel) and then the writing appeared twice. if you give the `Main` object a reference, then your problem should be fixed.